Trying to edit a 100% stacked bar chart inside PPT using OpenXml and C# and also using help of reading document using XML
To understand the problem, the motive of the program is to modify graph data according to requirement. Now I was removing the graph data from the xml data that it received from the powerpoint and thus I tried to remove the data and it worked temporarily. The problem that is arising is that if I do not remove the data from the excel that is filling the powerpoint graph and remove from the bar graph, the bar graph disappars and the values also is not present, but, as soon as I check the edit data excel, the graph reappears and thus I came to a conclusion that removing the excel value itself that is embedded in the graph, will modify the graph. So the git link is the code I am testing you can clone to see what happens.
https://github.com/Bhaskar365/Edit_Existing_OneHundredPercent_Stacked_Bar_Chart_in_PPT_Using_OpenXML_CSharp.git . Any help on this would be appreciated and for understanding I will attach the photo of a sample chart and chart after modifications.
So, initially a sample chart looks like this - 
To get this chart, in powerpoint -> insert -> chart -> Bar -> 100% stacked bar
After modification in the chart in the ppt like removal of one category, it would look like this - 
Any help is appreciated.
